# Calculate word count in ms-word by heading type

Tags: vba, ms-word

Microsoft Word only provides a word count for the entire document. The following VBA code works well enough, but others might have a better approach.

If you open the Visual Basic editor in Word, paste this in, execut and view the Immediate Window, it'll traverse the active document and calculate the word count based on the use of Header 1 and Header 2 chapter headings (which is useful for writers like me)

```
    Sub CountByChapterHeading()

    Dim sectionCount As Long
    Dim chapterCount As Long
    Dim chapterHeader As String

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    
        If para.Range.Words(1).Style = "Heading 1" Then
        
            'As we get to each section (Header 1), check to see if the last chapter (Header 2) was shown
            If chapterCount > 0 Then Debug.Print "    " & chapterHeader & " : " & chapterCount
        
            chapterHeader = CStr(para.Range)
            chapterHeader = Replace(chapterHeader, Chr(13), "")
            
            If sectionCount > 0 Then
                'Provide a subtotal by section (Header 1)
                Debug.Print "____________"
                Debug.Print sectionCount
                Debug.Print ""
            End If
            
            Debug.Print chapterHeader
            
            chapterCount = 0
            sectionCount = 0
        
        Else
        
            If para.Range.Words(1).Style = "Heading 2" Then
                'First print the previous sections details then start a new recording
                If chapterCount > 0 Then Debug.Print "    " & chapterHeader & " : " & chapterCount
                'And the new details are...
                chapterHeader = CStr(para.Range)
                chapterHeader = Replace(chapterHeader, Chr(13), "")
                chapterCount = 0
                
            Else
                    chapterCount = chapterCount + para.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
                    sectionCount = sectionCount + para.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
            End If
      
        End If
    
    Next para

End Sub
```

Here's a sample output
[image: Output in VBA]

Comment: See, for example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/macro-to-compute-headings-word-counts/8bba18a7-e931-41d7-9481-1bcff364dd3a